# Possible Unintended Reference comparison; to get a value comparison, cast the left hand side to type 'string'

Tags: c#

I'm using this code in order to show a specific record from the database when the user select a value from a combobox, but I constantly get the warning as was specified in the title and none of the question asked before with the same topic helped..

```
public int id;
string [] afisare = new string[2]; 

public formularCurse()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        afisare[0] = "Traseu";
        afisare[1] = "Bilete";
        cmbCurse.DataSource = afisare;
        id = 0;
    }
 private void grdCurse_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (cmbCurse.SelectedItem == "Traseu") { popTraseu(); }
                else if (cmbCurse.SelectedItem == "Bilete") { popBilete(); }

            }
             catch (Exception er) { MessageBox.Show(er.Message); }
    }
```

The methods `popTraseu()` and `popBilete()` was declared

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
        try
        {
            if ((string)cmbCurse.SelectedItem == "Traseu") { popTraseu(); }
            else if ((string)cmbCurse.SelectedItem == "Bilete") { popBilete(); }
        }
         catch (Exception er) { MessageBox.Show(er.Message); }
```